# Renaming Table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to rename the table but getting error...please help me to solve.I'm using mysql query browser

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'caste c to religion' at line 1

Query:

```
rename caste to religion;
```

Comment: `rename table caste to religion` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html)

Comment: It's working,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it's great to read just a little documentation. [Mysql Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html)

There is 2 ways to rename a table :

```
RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE old_table RENAME new_table;
```

You must have the ALTER and DROP privilege to rename a table.

In your case the query would be :

```
RENAME TABLE caste TO religion;
```

Comment: It's Working..Thank You

Comment: Getting error while drop table religion Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails